# Unable to get local issuer certificate error with unusual certificate chain

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, letsencrypt

I've encountered a frustrating issue with my SSL implementation due to what may be related to [Let's Encrypts CA-X3 certificate expiration](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021/).

Forewarned that I am a developer with limited understanding of SSL.

Testing the request in Postman is giving me the error:

```
SSL Error: Unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Running `openssl s_client -connect abcd.mydomain.com.au:443` shows the following certificate chain:

```
Certificate chain
0 s:CN = *.abcd.mydomain.com.au
  i:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
1 s:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3    
  i:O= Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
```

Could somebody please help me diagnose and rectify this problem? I'm unsure where/how to diagnose and fix the issue.

```
OS: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
OpenSSL: 1.1.1
ca-certificates: 20211016~18.04.1
```

Comment: Have you updated your `ca-certificates` package recently?

Comment: @garethTheRed No I haven't messed with any of the certificates or anything yet, although I believe the previous developer has attempted some fixes that have not worked so the system could be in a strange state.

Comment: How old is the certificate being sent? What does your webserver's configuration look like? Are you using fullchain.pem or have you done some manual configuration for SSLCertificateChainFile? It looks like your server is still providing an obsolete certificate chain that you couldn't possibly have gotten from their ACME servers anymore, so that feels like manual copypasting was done.

Answer (score 1):

This error is caused by your system thinking that the certificate you are using is a self-signed certificate. This happens because the Let's Encrypt CA has been "recently" (Sep 2021) updated and is not in your trusted certificate store.

In order to fix this, as suggested in the comments, upgrade your `ca-certificates` package. This package contains all the trusted CAs in Ubuntu and has been updated to reflect this change in the LE certificate chain.

You can do this with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt --only-upgrade install ca-certificates
```

Note: the fact that you're asking this question shows that you don't have a process in place for regular system updates. You might want to talk to your ops department or automate upgrades using something like [UnattendedUpgrades](https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades#:%7E:text=The%20purpose%20of%20unattended%2Dupgrades,send%20you%20emails%20about%20updates.)

---

This error can also be caused by missing intermediate certificates. In order to fix this, you can add the `/etc/letsencrypt/live/$domain/chain.pem` to your Postman configuration. (no idea how to do that, never worked with Postman)

Comment: Thank you @mtak I ran those commands and was informed that: ca-certificates is already the newest version (20211016~18.04.1)

Comment: The guy working on this before me did mention something about having edited the fullchain file. I get the feeling some "manual editing" has gone on but is not being admitted to.

Comment: In that case, all bets are off... You might try running `sudo c_rehash` and/or `sudo update-ca-certificates`. Can you verify that `/etc/ssl/certs/ISRG_Root_X1.pem` exists? If so, the `c_rehash` and `update-ca-certificates` should fix it.

Comment: `/etc/ssl/certs/ISRG_Root_X1.pem` is present. I then ran `sudo c_rehash` and got the following output: `Doing /usr/lib/ssl/certs
WARNING: Skipping duplicate certificate ca-certificates.crt
WARNING: Skipping duplicate certificate ca-certificates.crt
WARNING: letsencrypt-stg-root-dst.pem does not contain a certificate or CRL: skipping
WARNING: letsencrypt-stg-root-x1.pem does not contain a certificate or CRL: skipping
`

Comment: Running `update-ca-certificates` produced no changes: `Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
done.
`

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is related to DST X1, but actually goes a bit deeper than the usual "expired CA" topics.

The trusted CA update isn't going to help here (yet), because the server is currently offering outdated LE intermediates that can *only* be linked to DST CA – the TLS client has no way of associating it with the ISRG CA in the first place. The chain that you're seeing *used to be* correct a very long time ago, before the "ISRG Root CA" was established.

(Other similar threads that are 'solved' by uninstalling the DST CA are actually using a newer certificate chain, one where the LE intermediate is instead signed by ISRG CA and *that* is cross-signed by DST CA, allowing for two alternative validation paths.)

In other words, your s_client output shows a very outdated certificate chain – one that LE's ACME servers stopped providing long ago, even long before the Sep2021 DST expiry. This indicates one of two things:

- The certificate was installed manually, without setting up any automatic renewal, and left like that for several years (and nobody cared about it expiring). Forcing a renewal would probably fix the issue.

  - Or perhaps the ACME client you have was ACMEv1-only, and stopped working when LE fully replaced that with ACMEv2, so automatic renewals stopped happening as well. (This happened to acmetool.)
- Or, the certificate *is* being auto-renewed, but the automation is giving the wrong certificate file to the web server. For example, the issued server certificate is being read from the cert.pem updated by your ACME client like it should, but the "certificate chain" is being read from a chain.pem that's been manually copy&pasted and so isn't picking up the updates from ACME.

  The exact setup here varies depending on which ACME client you're using, but in all cases the webserver should use *only* files from the ACME client's "live" or "output" folder. If you're using Certbot, then `fullchain.pem` has the server's certificate *with* the correct intermediate chain (for webservers that prefer a combined file), and `chain.pem` in the same directory has just the intermediates (for webservers that prefer them separate).

  - For example, in Apache httpd, this would be correct:

    ```
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
    ```

    Outdated in 2.4 but acceptable:

    ```
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem
    ```

    Not correct:

    ```
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /root/letsencrypt_chain.pem
    ```

  In any case, no manual editing of the .pem files should *ever* be needed (other than possibly converting them to another format).

But I would say just delete the certificate and redo it from scratch, using an up-to-date ACME client (certbot, lego, or one of the shellscript-based monstrosities) – and leaving comments for the next person. Though before deleting it, do a quick look using `openssl x509 -text` or `certtool -i` to check what domains it was issued for.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. To ask what is probably a silly question - how do I delete the certificate (as in which file(s) should I remove)?

Comment: I don't know where they are on your system (especially if manual "fixes" were done), so I would suggest starting at your webserver's config – find the SSL or TLS configuration, it'll have the certificate paths. But do also check the "usual" locations like /etc/letsencrypt and `certbot certificates` / `certbot delete`, if Certbot was in use; look also for traces of acme.sh, `.lego`, `dehydrated`.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this error is the misconfiguration of root and intermediate certificates during SSL communication between client and server. And the other cause can be a self-signed certificate as well.

Since you're using Ubuntu 18.04, you should ensure that your CA certificates are up to date. You mentioned that your ca-certificates version is 20211016~18.04.1, which seems relatively recent. However, Let's Encrypt has transitioned to ISRG Root X1 as the default root certificate, replacing DST Root CA X3.

Try updating your CA certificates by running:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --only-upgrade ca-certificates

Also, you can update the SSL bundle. Get the CA bundle file and save it on your server. This solution I have found through https://www.ssl2buy.com/wiki/fix-ssl-certificate-problem-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate

To download Let's encrypt bundle - https://letsencrypt.org/certs/lets-encrypt-x3-cross-signed.pem
If anyone using another CA certificate, then one can download the CA bundle from here - https://www.ssl2buy.com/wiki/ssl-intermediate-and-root-ca-bundle